# Security measures before inserting data into MySQL in Django

Tags: mysql, django, security

I have this ajax code that sends the text of textarea to my Django code

```
       $.ajax({
         url:'/fun/submitblog',
         data:{
           'text':$(".blogtext").val().trim()
         },
         datatype:'json',
         success:function(data){
           console.log(data);
         }
       });
```

I receive this data like this in Django:

```
def submitblog(request):
    txt = request.GET.get('text', None)
```

Now i want to insert this 'txt' into database,but i want to do it maximumly safe.What safety precautions should be taken?

Comment: Use the **ORM**, do **not** write queries yourself. Furthermore do not use `txt` *directly* in slicing, field names, etc. Since those are typically more vulnerable.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks! But what do you mean by not using txt directly? Should i assign it to new value and update the table after editing the value?

Comment: And don't use GET requests to update the database; use POST.

Comment: @IBMR: no, in case you use such text for *slicing*, pass it through the `int(..)` function, to ensure it is *really* an `int`.

Comment: Furthermore, like Daniel says, you typically *never* update things through `GET`, only through `POST`. Imagine that the user refreshes the browser, then he/she has submitted the same value twice.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem this objects are not inside of a `form` tag,so that probably won't happen.

Comment: Still it is simply not how REST was designed. GET is for *getting* things, POST is for *changing* things. In fact some webservers have sanity checks that a `GET` does *not* alter the database at all.

Comment: This has nothing to do with forms; you are updating via Ajax, so forms are irrelevant. You should change your JS to send a POST request, not a GET.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you,i did change it!